# how to get data using $_POST method when form submitted by $.ajax method

Tags: php, jquery

**JavaScript** function

```
function sub()
{
var url = "showpdf.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    success: function(response)
    {
        document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
    }
});
}
```

I am calling this function in html like this:

```
<input type = "button" value="Go" onclick="sub()">
```

in `showpdf.php` file I write bellow code to get form data

```
$academic = $_POST['academic'];
$uni = $_POST['University'];
```

but I am getting this error

> Undefined index: academic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the data from the input fields and send through the ajax post call

```
function sub()
{
var url = "showpdf.php";
var university  = jQuery("#university").val(); //id of the university input field
var academic  = jQuery("#academic").val(); // id of the academic input field
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: { university: university, location: academic },
    success: function(response)
    {
        document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: thanks Tomi, 
hey can you tell me how to access university and location variable inside showpdf.php??

Comment: You can access with $_POST["university"] and $_POST["location"].
The pairs in data set {university:university, location:academic} pass the post to your page, the "university" and "location" are then transformed as post variables with its values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in your data into the ajax call, you aren't actually sending anything to the php script at the moment.

you can add data to your ajax call as follows

```
function sub()
{
var url = "showpdf.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: {'academic': 'wiiiieee'},
    success: function(response)
    {
        document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
    }
});
}
```

where `data` is a Object containing key->value pairs

Answer (score 1):

Pass you data into the ajax call:

Ex:

//get your post data into these variables

```
var University; 
var academic;
```

//and pass it like

```
var dataString = 'academic='+ academic+ '&University=' + University;

$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: dataString,
        url: url,
        success: function(response)
        {
            document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any data through with the ajax call.

```
function sub(data)
{
    var url = "showpdf.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        url: url,
        success: function(response)
        {
            document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
}

var data = {"academic": "something", "University": "something else"};
sub(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're getting or sending data? I do not understand, if you are sending lack DATA, you can send serialized form as follows: $("#form").serialize(); , #form is ID

> function sub(){
>
> var url = "showpdf.php";
>
> var dataString= $("#form").serialize();
>
> $.ajax({
>
> type: "post",
>
> url: url,
>
> data: dataString,
>
> success: function(response)
>
> {
>
> document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
>
> }
>
> });
>
> }